# Webservices in Eclipse using Axis2: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: eclipse, web-services, apache-axis, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I've been struggling a while now with web services in Eclipse.
Every time I get something working, it merely seems to be based on luck and I've tried everything in numerous ways.

My latest problem involves the following:
I've got a java application which uses a lot of external references (jars).
I've exported this java project to a simple jar file using the Fat-jar plugin (http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) to make sure the exported jar contains all the needed resources.
I then created a dynamic web project and added the jar from before to this project.
When I do some basic tests, everything works fine, i.e. Eclipse finds all the needed references.

However, when I try to create a web service, whose methods use the exact same logic as the tests, I get errors.
I don't understand why I get a ClassNotFoundException because, like i said before, when doing local tests, Eclipse finds all the needed resources.

```
[INFO] Deploying module: addressing-1.6.1 - file:/C:/Users/Flamant/My     master/code/WorkspaceEclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps    /org.openmarkov.webservice.engine/WEB-INF/modules/addressing-1.6.1.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: metadataExchange-1.6.1 - file:/C:/Users/Flamant/My     master/code/WorkspaceEclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps    /org.openmarkov.webservice.engine/WEB-INF/modules/mex-1.6.1.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: mtompolicy-1.6.1 - file:/C:/Users/Flamant/My     master/code/WorkspaceEclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps    /org.openmarkov.webservice.engine/WEB-INF/modules/mtompolicy-1.6.1.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: ping-1.6.1 - file:/C:/Users/Flamant/My     master/code/WorkspaceEclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps    /org.openmarkov.webservice.engine/WEB-INF/modules/ping-1.6.1.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: script-1.6.1 - file:/C:/Users/Flamant/My     master/code/WorkspaceEclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps    /org.openmarkov.webservice.engine/WEB-INF/modules/scripting-1.6.1.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: soapmonitor-1.6.1 - file:/C:/Users/Flamant/My     master/code/WorkspaceEclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps    /org.openmarkov.webservice.engine/WEB-INF/modules/soapmonitor-1.6.1.mar
[INFO] The Engine service, which is not valid, caused java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     [Lorg/openmarkov/webservice/Finding;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.bytecode.MethodTable.loadMethods(MethodTable.java:43)
at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.bytecode.MethodTable.<init>(MethodTable.java:33)
at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.<init>(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:141)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.fillAxisService(Utils.java:453)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:389)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.buildServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:101)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:178)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:82)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:813)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:370)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:142)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.loadServices(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:283)
at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:95)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:60)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1043)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5279)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openmarkov.webservice.Finding
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
... 34 more

[INFO] org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     [Lorg/openmarkov/webservice/Finding;
[INFO] Deploying Web service: version.aar - file:/C:/Users/Flamant/My master/code/WorkspaceEclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/org.openmarkov.webservice.engine/WEB-INF/services/version.aar
[WARN] No transportReceiver for org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener found. An instance for HTTP will be configured automatically. Please update your axis2.xml file!
apr 11, 2012 10:51:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
apr 11, 2012 10:51:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8010"]
apr 11, 2012 10:51:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1928 ms
```

If anyone has an idea, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: how are you creating web service ? And which axis2 version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are facing NoClassDefFoundError, which occurs when the required libs are not found at runtime...Check the libs are at your runtime classpath..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I indeed came to the same conclusion. However, I still don't know how to solve this. I've added all the needed .jars and projects to: (1) the lib directory, (2) the java Build path in properties and (3) the deployment assembly in properties.

Comment: Hi, Add the libs at your runtime classpath...Go to project view specific class/project right click-->Run as-->Run configurations--> set the classpath there(add jars there)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean when in the eclipse environment your web service works fine, but in your dynamic web project does not work?  missing jar in your dynamic web project?

Comment: No, in the dynamic web project I've made a 'test'-package where I call methods from the imported .jar-file. These all work fine. It's only when I try to create a webservice (from a class, that uses the exact same logic as the tests from the test-package), that the error occurs.

Comment: If all needed jar are present, check if it is possible that you have jar conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure atleast these 
      activation-1.1.jar,
            axiom-api-1.2.8.jar,
            axiom-dom-1.2.8.jar,
            axiom-impl-1.2.8.jar,
            axis2-adb-1.5.1.jar,
            axis2-kernel-1.5.1.jar,
            axis2-transport-http-1.5.1.jar,
            axis2-transport-local-1.5.1.jar,
            commons-codec-1.3.jar,
            commons-fileupload-1.2.jar,
            commons-httpclient-3.1.jar,
            commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,
            geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar,
            httpcore-4.0.jar,
            mail-1.4.jar,
            neethi-2.0.4.jar,
            woden-api-1.0M8.jar,
            woden-impl-dom-1.0M8.jar,
            wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar,
            wstx-asl-3.2.4.jar,
            XmlSchema-1.4.3.jar

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too. In my case I haven't followed the steps clearly in [[1]](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html) article. In step 12, do not change the "Service Project" name.

Comment: Please add some more detail to your answer rather than referencing an external link.